# Drawing Canvas on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, awt

I'm trying to draw simple shapes with Canvas, in this class I've set the painting

```
public class Game extends Canvas{
    //FIELDS
    public int WIDTH  = 1024;
    public int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;

    //METHODS
    public void start(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        paint(null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

And in this the Window

```
public class MainW {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game ga = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(ga);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ga.start();

    }

}
```

It works, but the JFrame is not adapting to the Canvas. I have to manually resize the window to see the objects. How can I pack it so that JFrame automatically encompasses the Canvas?

EDIT:
That's really weird. While frame.pack() is indeed essential, it's not enough.
What I did was change the start method and turn it into a constructor, like that:

```
    public class Game extends Canvas{
        //FIELDS
        public int WIDTH  = 1024;
        public int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;

        //METHODS
        public void Game(){
        Dimension size = new Dimension (WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }
```

then, from the other class, Eclipse complained about calling the constructor directly(E.G. ga.Game), so I followed it's tip and changed to:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game ga = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(ga);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ga.getName();

    }
```

This way I achieve what I have in mind but I really don't know why I can't call the constructor.

Comment: Add `frame.pack();` between `add(ga)` and `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Don't mix AWT and Swing components needlessly. YOu should be drawing on a JPanel and in its `paintCompoment(...)` override method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what it is you're trying to do, but you should NEVER be calling `paint` and especially not pass it `null`.

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting works.

In order to get the window to size to you component, you need to provide it some important information.

While `Window#pack` is the method you are looking for, it will not help you unless you provide appropriate sizing hints.

In this case, you need to override the `getPreferredSize` method of you component and provide an appropriate size value.  `Window#pack` will use this value to determine what size it needs to be in order to accommodate it.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaint();
    }

    public TestPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillOval(100, 100, 30, 30);
        }
    }
}
```

The paint chain is very important and you should avoid breaking it at all coasts.  Make sure you always call `super.paintXxx` or be prepared for some serious weirdness

Also may want to have a read of [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.awt.Window.pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) (`JFrame` indirectly extends `Window`):

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents.

```
    // ...
    frame.add(ga);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After painting on canvas try repaint the `JFrame`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game ga = new Game();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(ga);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    ga.start();

    //repaint here
    frame.repaint();
}
```

Also note that:

`frame.pack` for fixing the size issue.

`frame.revalidate` sometimes help when adding or removing components in runtime.