# Centering an imported png

Tags: java, swing, label, png

Basically I am fairly new to java still and imported a simple png over another, It's a proof of concept for myself and I would assume is very informal coding. None the less I don't know how to move the second png as it puts it self at `(0,0,0)` in the top left once the application opens.

```
public class DisplayImage extends JFrame {

    public DisplayImage() {
        initUI();
    }

    private ImageIcon loadImage() {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("/Users/980057130/Desktop/pixil-frame-0.png");
        return ii;
    }

    private ImageIcon loadImage1() {
        ImageIcon iii = new ImageIcon("/Users/980057130/Desktop/Dynamic-Dungeon.png");
        return iii;
    }

    private void initUI() {                   
        ImageIcon ii = loadImage();
        ImageIcon iii = loadImage1();

        JLabel label = new JLabel(iii);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(ii);

        createLayout(label);
        createLayout(label1);

        label = new JLabel();

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(label), "Center");

        setTitle("Dynamic Dungeon");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow and to the friendly java community. Few pointers for you on this. If you are interested in drawing images then looking in to painting on a canvas might be a better approach. Using Labels is more in to the realms of laying out a GUI and when you are doing that you won't typically be trying to draw labels on top of one another.

You could check out this question [Drawing Canvas on JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922443/drawing-canvas-on-jframe)

which involves someone drawing on to a canvas, which you could try to use to draw your images.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center one image on top of another the easiest way is to let a layout manager do this for you.

So the basic logic would be:

```
JLabel foreground = new JLabel( new ImageIcon() );
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
background.add(foreground, new GridBagConstraints() );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( background );
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When using the GridBagLayout with default constraints any component added will automatically be centered in the space available.

Note, a JLabel is not really designed to be a container, so this approach will only work if the foreground image is smaller than the background image.